# Login to YouTube app with different Google account w/o gmail access

Tags: gmail, youtube

I can login to YouTube with a different Google account, but this account got saved in setting/ system/ account section, which means whoever get access to the tablet can access my gmail also. Is there anyway just login to YouTube only?

Comment: Sorry but Login to an Google account always activates it on your device an thus allows access to all Google services. That is the purpose of a Single-Sign-On system - even if you don't want it to work this way.